# Javascript if and else statement not working

Tags: javascript, php

This page has HTML, PHP, Javascript, and jQuery. My goal is to cause the code to display the word **Public** if the value is **1** and display **Private** if the value is **0**.

On the page I simply tested

```
<p class="title" style="text-align:left;"><strong>Privacy:</strong> {%=file.privacy||''%}</p>
```

This test displayed either a 1 or 0 depending on the database info so this told me the db query and needed information is available and accurate.

My next step I need to accomplish is to then make a javascript code that will compare if

```
{%=file.privacy||''%} == 1
```

and then display the word **Public** or if

```
{%=file.privacy||''%} == 0
```

then display the word **Private**.

**Here is the code attempt which  failed:**

```
<script> if( file.privacy = 1 ){
   document.write("<b>Public</b>");
}else{
   document.write("<b>Private</b>");
}</script>
```

Thanks for the suggestions and your solution (adding another "=") fixed the javascript code above. I still have an issue here because I am nesting one script tag inside of another script tag. Time to research that for a solution...

Comment: Try `==` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using assignment instead of comparison. 
Try this

```
<script> if( file.privacy == 1 ){
   document.write("<b>Public</b>");
  }else{
  document.write("<b>Private</b>");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it with no luck. I am going to edit my original post with the whole block of code and a screenshot of the error.